# DataTables Warning: Requested unknown parameter 'pCodigo' for row 0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, datatables

I'm trying to populate a table on a button click, getting the data from an ASP.NET ApiController. I've tried with almost all solutions posted in SO to other similar issues but always get that error.
Hope someone sees the problem.

The html markup:

```html
<input type="button" ID="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" class="btn btn-success" value="Buscar" />
<table id="ResultsTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="font-size: 11px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Codigo")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Descripcion")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Marca")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("IC")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("IV")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Tarifa")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Precio")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("P")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Total")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Central")%></th>
        <th><%=GetLiteral("Centro")%></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

The JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SearchTable = $("#ResultsTable").DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "pCodigo" },
            { data: "rDescripcion" },
            { data: "rMarca" },
            { data: "xIndiceCarga" },
            { data: "xIndiceVelocidad" },
            { data: "TARIFA" },
            { data: "PRECIO" },
            { data: "PROVIENE" },
            { data: "TOTAL" },
            { data: "CENTRAL" },
            { data: "CENTRO" }
        ],
        ordering: false,
        searching: false
    });

    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        var searchText = $("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/api/ProductSearch/")%>' + searchText + '/0138107',
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(result) {
            SearchTable.clear().draw();
            SearchTable.rows.add(result).draw();
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("FAIL: " + textStatus + " = " + errorThrown);
        });
    });
}
```

A data sample:

```js
[{
"RowError": "",
"RowState": 2,
"Table": [{
    "pCodigo": "10006908",
    "rDescripcion": "225/65/16-VAN100(112R)CO B-B-72-2",
    "rMarca": "CONTI",
    "xDibujo": 254176,
    "xIndiceCarga": "112",
    "xIndiceVelocidad": "R",
    "xEje": 0,
    "xAplicacion": 0,
    "xDecimales": false,
    "xTipoIVA": 2,
    "xTasa": 2.550,
    "TARIFA": 203.50,
    "PRECIO": 105.54,
    "PROVIENE": "LG",
    "COLOR": 8454143,
    "TOTAL": 3.00,
    "CENTRAL": 2.00,
    "CENTRO": 2.00,
    "xControl": true
},
{
    "pCodigo": "30000159",
    "rDescripcion": "225/65/16-RF09(112R)ROTALLA E-C-73-3",
    "rMarca": "ROTAL",
    "xDibujo": 253405,
    "xIndiceCarga": "112",
    "xIndiceVelocidad": "R",
    "xEje": 0,
    "xAplicacion": 0,
    "xDecimales": false,
    "xTipoIVA": 2,
    "xTasa": 2.550,
    "TARIFA": 69.00,
    "PRECIO": 49.29,
    "PROVIENE": "LG",
    "COLOR": 16777088,
    "TOTAL": 89.00,
    "CENTRAL": 55.00,
    "CENTRO": 55.00,
    "xControl": true
}],
"ItemArray": ["30000159",
"225/65/16-RF09(112R)ROTALLA E-C-73-3",
"ROTAL",
253405,
"112",
"R",
0,
0,
false,
2,
2.550,
69.00,
49.29,
"LG",
16777088,
89.00,
55.00,
55.00,
true],
"HasErrors": false
}]
```

Note: The GetLiteral function in html markup returns a string with the column name internationalized, that can be different from the text shown and column name. I think that's not the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must insert the `Table` array :

```js
}).success(function(result) {
   SearchTable.clear().draw();
   SearchTable.rows.add(result[0].Table).draw();
})
```

alternatively you can cycle through the `Table` array and add each item individually :

```js
}).success(function(result) {
   SearchTable.clear().draw();
   for (var i=0;i<result.Table.length;i++) {
      SearchTable.row.add(result[0].Table[i]).draw();
   }
})
```

Comment: That doesn't throw any error, but also doesn't render anything on the table.

Comment: @Sergio Updated, added the answer too early :( did not made distinction between rows and row.

Comment: I'm so sorry but still doesn't work. The first solution does nothing. and the second throws 'Table' not defined error.
When I inspected result, I've seen something strange. It has no Table root element, but twelve nodes (the rows). Each node has a Table and Itemarray subnodes, the first containing all the rows and the second the field data for that node.
But all the info is shown with indexes and field names are missing.

Comment: @Sergio, dont be sry for that!! it is me who did not realized that your JSON actually is an array with 1 item, holding all other items, incl the Table array. So `result[0].Table` works for sure, have tested it myself. Sry for that, I just assumed your JSON was constructed more straigt, and focused solely on the Table item :(

Comment: Yup! that worked, thanks! But still I don't understand why the json response gets in that manner. %/

Comment: @Sergio, hard to say without knowing how you create the JSON on the backend. It is a little bit none typically, I give you that :)